# Select Substring From Linq.Repeat

Tags: c#, linq, select, repeat

I have a very long string, in c# it looks like:

```
String currentStrings = "\\u0000\\u0001\\u0002\\u0003\\u0004"..."\\uFFFF";  //... means repeating
```

I need get the hex of every substring, such:

```
String newString = "00000001000200030004"..."FFFF";
```

I'm wrote linq:

```
var newString = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(currentStrings, 16).Select(s => s.Substring(2, 4)));
```

But it returns `"00000000000000000000000"..."0000".`

I know, the reason of this - it 2 in select, but I don't know how to get the beginning position in current repeated substring.

Comment: What is your primary goal? What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just `Split` on `\u` and use `string.Concat` to concatenate them:

```
string currentStrings = "\\u0000\\u0001\\u0002\\u0003\\u0004\\uFFFF";
var result = string.Concat(currentStrings.Split(new[] { "\\u" }, 
                                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)); 

// output
00000001000200030004FFFF
```

**Edit:** To get the `chars`:

```
var chars = currentStrings
       .Split(new[] { "\\u" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(x => (char) Convert.ToInt32(x, 16))
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i also must create chars of every of this substrings. In Linq i know how it to do, but there... 
Maybe you do it quickly? (char)Convert.ToInt32(substring);

Comment: @user3041948 you should add that into your question. we can't guess what's your actual requirement is.

Comment: I know, but i can't imagine that we able to do this without Linq.

Answer (score 1):

You need substrings at postions: 2, 8, ..., 6 * N - 4, where N is a number of unicode entities in your string.

Well, in LINQ:

```
var N = currentStrings.Length / 6; // each entity has 6 characters long
var substrings = Enumerable.Range(1, N)
                           .Select(n => 6 + n - 4)
                           .Select(n => currentStrings.Substring(n, 4));

var result = string.Join("", substrings);
```